# Parsing JSON in Python and writing to Excel file

Tags: python, json

I have the following JSON saved in a text file called test.xlsx.txt. The JSON is as follows:

```
{"RECONCILIATION": {0: "Successful"}, "ACCOUNT": {0: u"21599000"}, "DESCRIPTION": {0: u"USD to be accrued. "}, "PRODUCT": {0: "7500.0"}, "VALUE": {0: "7500.0"}, "AMOUNT": {0: "7500.0"}, "FORMULA": {0: "3 * 2500 "}}
```

The following is my python code:

```
f = open(path_to_analysis_results,'r')
message = f.read()
datastore = json.loads(str(message))
print datastore
f.close()
```

With the json.loads, I get the error "*ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 21 (char 20)*". I have tried with json.load, json.dump and json.dumps, with all of them giving various errors. All I want to do is to be able to extract the key and the corresponding value and write to an Excel file. I have figured out how to write data to an Excel file, but am stuck with parsing this json.

```
RECONCILIATION : Successful
ACCOUNT : 21599000
DESCRIPTION : USD to be accrued.
PRODUCT : 7500.0
VALUE : 7500.0
AMOUNT : 7500.0
FORMULA : 3 * 2500
```

I would like the data to be in the above format to be able to write them to an Excel sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mike mentioned, your text file is not a valid JSON. It should be like:

```
{"RECONCILIATION": {"0": "Successful"}, "ACCOUNT": {"0": "21599000"}, "DESCRIPTION": {"0": "USD to be accrued. "}, "PRODUCT": {"0": "7500.0"}, "VALUE": {"0": "7500.0"}, "AMOUNT": {"0": "7500.0"}, "FORMULA": {"0": "3 * 2500 "}}
```

Note: keys are within doube quotes as JSON requires double quotes. And, your code should be (without **str()**):

```
import json

f = open(path_to_analysis_results,'r')
message = f.read()
print(message) # print message before, just to check it.
datastore = json.loads(message) # note: str() is not required. Message is already a string
print (datastore)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your txt file does not contain valid JSON.

For starters, keys must be strings, not numbers.

The `u"..."` notation is not valid either.

You should fix your JSON first (maybe run it through a linter such as https://jsonlint.com/ to make sure it's valid).